# Changing inner ASPX code of a PlaceHolder?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, placeholder

I use a `Repeater` to read from different tables, since tables has different columns, I'll have to use a dynamic template.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="tableData" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
           <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:PlaceHolder ID="tableBody" runat="server">
                            </asp:PlaceHolder>
           </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

But VS 2010 doesn't seem to recognize the placeholder nested in the repeater.

So I tried to let the placeholder generate the repeater, but how can I change the inner code by hand? There's no "innerHtml" option.

**UPDATE**

I'm note sure If placeholder is approriate , but what I want is to generate stuff inside `<ItemTemplate>` dynamically , which is things like `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "username") %>`

Because I'm reading different table column from different tables , this need to be selected base on the table user wanted.

So I need to modify the ASPX code before it's being processed ,  is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: You can send more detail why PlaceHolder is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio won't pick up a control that is nested in a Repeater. For this, you will need to use FindControl to access the control in the Repeater.

Here are two examples you can use to access a control within a Repeater.

1) Looping through Repeater items

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in tableData.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var ph = (PlaceHolder)item.FindControl("tableBody");

        //Do something with your placeholder
        ph.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

2) Use the `ItemDataBound` event on the Repeater

```
void tableData_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var ph = (PlaceHolder) e.Item.FindControl("tableBody");

        //Do something with your placeholder
        ph.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

If you plan on using the `ItemDataBound` event, you will need to add the following attribute to your Repeater:

```
OnItemDataBound="tableData_ItemDataBound"
```

Could you clarify what you exactly want to do with your Placeholder? There is no "innerHTML" property for a Placeholder. I think you are getting mistaken with JavaScript. I presume you want to populate your a control inside your repeater with some Html. You could use a Literal instead.

### Edit

Using a Literal to populate the Repeater dynamically based on data from database.

```
void tableData_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        //Get column from datasource
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

        var lit = (Literal) e.Item.FindControl("MyLiteral");

        //Populate Literal with data
        StringBuilder htmlMarkup = new StringBuilder();

        htmlMarkup.AppendFormat("{0}<br />", drv["username"].ToString());
        htmlMarkup.AppendFormat("{0}<br />", drv["Name"].ToString());
        htmlMarkup.AppendFormat("{0}<br />", drv["lastname"].ToString());

        lit.Text = htmlMarkup.ToString();
    }
}
```

As you can see I am retrieving the data and outputting what I want in the format I want.

Comment: From looking at your update, when you mean you generate dynamic things like "username" to your repeater, I don't think a Placeholder will work. Use a Literal instead and then use an "OnItemDataBound" event (as stated in my post) to populate the Literal in the Repeater. You pull out the data from your database table as required. I will update my post to see if that helps you.